# How to apply alternating row pattern to only one datagridview column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm hoping to find a way to apply my alternating row pattern to a single datagridview column.

I have a windows forms application using vb.net. Right Now I have a pattern that changes the backcolor of every other datagridview cell to a different color. My pattern is white then light blue. I've included an image below and my code. This code applies this pattern to the entire datagridview, but I only want to apply it to one, for instance the second column index.

```
           With Me.DataGridView1
                .DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
                .AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
            End With
```

[image]

Comment: You could add an if statement that checks the column name before applying your style?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an if statement to your datagridview's cellformatting event like this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ConditionalFormatting_StatusCell(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
        With Me.DataGridView1
            If e.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0 Then
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
            Else
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.AliceBlue
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This still won't work, the statements "DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White and DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue" will change the entire datagridview not just one column. Even though you specified if the column index is 2, the statements themselves are meant to change the entire datagridview. I appreciate your help though. :)

Comment: Ah I see, please see my edit which just uses modulus to check if the row is even or odd and assigns a color accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give alternate style to some column from grid
use cellformating event like this

```
Private Sub TDBGrid1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles TDBGrid1.CellFormatting
    With TDBGrid1
        If Not e.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex > 3 Then
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Cyan
        Else
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
        End If
    End With
    End Sub
```

Here i wanted alternate style to column index which is greater than 3